# Finding a value base on an "ID"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

How can I assign a "CityID" in "Customer Table" using customer's Address and a given "ProvinceID"?

```
(Province Table)
ID . ProvinceName
1 . . Ontario
2 . . Quebec
3 . . Nova Scotia
4 . . Quebec


(City Table)
ID . CityName . . . ProvinceID
1 . . Chatham . . . . . . 1
2 . . Chatham . . . . . . 2
3 . . Hudson . . . . . . . 1
4 . . Hudson . . . . . . . 2
5 . . New Glasgow . . 3
6 . . New Glasgow . . 4


(Customer Table)
ID . Address . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ProvinceID . CityID
1 . . 123 aStreet1 St., Chatham, Ontario . . . 1
2 . . 123 aStreet2 St., Chatham, Quebec . . . 2
3 . . 123 aStreet3 St., Hudson, Ontario . . . . 1
4 . . 123 aStreet4 St., Hudson, Quebec . . . . 2

Wrongly inputed Address
5 . . Ontario Chatham 123 aStreet1 St. . . . . 1
6 . . 123 aStreet1 St. Chatham Ontario . . . . 1
7 . . Chatham 123 aStret St. . . . . . . . . . . . . 1

Partal (Incomplete) Address
8 . . 123 Street New Glasgow Scotia . . . . . . 5
9 . . 123 Street Glasgow Quebec . . . . . . . . . 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

> =INDEX($A$11:$A$14,MATCH(1,(--(MID(B18,SEARCH(", ",B18)+2,SEARCH(", ",B18,SEARCH(", ",B18)+1)-SEARCH(", ",B18)-2)=$B$11:$B$14))*--(C18=$C$11:$C$14),0))

You need to apply this as an array calculation using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
Applying the formula with just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> won't work.

Comment: Please see the updated formula with an image illustration. I misread your original question the first time.

Comment: Please try the updated formula, the other image doesn't seem to work for illustration. Try this instead [link](http://s4.postimg.org/ehbs2zyvx/arraymatch.png)

Comment: You rock! the equation is amazing...but what if the "address" is of different format, eg.. some without a comma, and others have the provience, and city in front of the address, can I do a general search function to catch all the string?

Comment: Might not be that easy. Please, post some example variations and I'll look into it.

Comment: I have Added 3 more example, (Customer Table) ID 5 to 7, Thanks so much for your help

Comment: this should do it c+s+enter =INDEX($A$11:$A$14,MATCH(1,(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$11:$B$14,B18)))*--(C18=$C$11:$C$14),0))

Comment: keep in mind that this is contingent on the city name not being a part of a street name or province name.

Comment: That's awesome.. the formula is even shorter ^_^ but how about partal address? I have added 2 more customer, province and cities. You are amazing man, so lucky to have you helping me.